# Is com.google.android.gms.wearable.Asset encrypted?

Tags: android, wear-os

According to Google Wear OS Document, communication between mobile app and wear oss app is end-to-end encrypted.

And also they say, when we use `DataClient`, Data items is private to the application that make them.

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data/data-layer#send-and-sync-with-API

Then my Question is that is `com.google.android.gms.wearable.Asset` which is made using `DataClient` api also encrypted in file system?